# Oracle: How can I move an index on LOB column to another tablespace without moving the underlying LOB column?

Tags: oracle, indexing, lob

How can I move an index on `LOB column` to another tablespace without moving the underlying `LOB column` ?

It doesn't work like normal index movement i.e. :

```
ALTER INDEX <> REBUILD TABLESPACE <> ONLINE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a different tablespace for the LOB and its index.  If you want to move the LOB index you must also move the LOB, according to [this AskTOM thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=lob-tablespace-moving-a-lob):

```
alter table table_Name move lob(lob_name) store as (tablespace tablespace_name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: thank you @Jon Heller for the contribution to my very old post in my SO history.